# Ruby mperham/connection_pool difference between ConnectionPool and ConnectionPool::Wrapper

Tags: ruby, connection-pool

in following https://github.com/mperham/connection_pool, Can anybody guide me what is the difference between ConnectionPool and ConnectionPool::Wrapper ? Under what circumstances one should use ConnectionPool::Wrapper ? Pros/cons of each method if they are similar ? I am finding it hard to understand by reading documentations https://github.com/mperham/connection_pool

Comment: As always, `Wrapper` can be used to wrap an existing pool, `ConnectionPool` provides it’s own implementation.

Comment: Pardon me for my poor understanding, But what do you mean to wrap an existing pool ?

Comment: To wrap e. g. `redis` pool, provided by `redis`.

Comment: Reading through this thread will help explain the purpose of the wrapper https://github.com/mperham/connection_pool/issues/105